# Creating Object with name parameters constructor in Powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, named-parameters

I have C# constructor

```
class A {
   public A (name="",version=""){
     //do something
   }
}
```

The corresponding DLL is imported in Powershell.
I want to create the `A` object by passing named parameters.

```
$a = New-Object ABC.XYZ.A -ArgumentList @()  //pass named params
```

I couldn't find the doc/example to create object with `constructor which takes optional named parameters [there are around 20 params]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not think it is possible, but you can work around it by deriving from the class with 20 parameters. See the following

```
$Source = @"
namespace DontCare
{
    /**/
    public class TheCrazyClassWith20parametersCtor
    {
        public TheCrazyClassWith20parametersCtor(/* 20 named parameters here*/)
        {}
    }

    public class MyWrapper : TheCrazyClassWith20parametersCtor
    {
        public MyWrapper(int param1, string param2)
        : base(
            /* use named parameters here*/
        )
        {} 
    }
}
"@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $Source -Language CSharp

New-Object -TypeName DontCare.MyWrapper -ArgumentList 42,"Hi!"
```

HTH